# Puppy Linux Live CD: "Symbolic Link to Unsupported Reparse Point"

Tags: mount, symlink, livecd, puppy-linux

Here are a few specs:

1. Windows 10 Pro
2. Slacko Puppy 6.3
3. 700 MB CD
4. 16 GB RAM
5. 2 TB HDD

Currently, to do some testing, I am running Puppy Linux from a live CD and attempting to access the files on my mounted C drive. I am booting from restart - and not from shutdown - to avoid the fast-boot in Windows 10. However, although most files work fine in terms of renaming, deleting, etc., many files in C:\Windows (and everything in C:\Windows\system32) come up as caution symbols with the tool tip "Symbolic Link to Unsupported Reparse Point." I booted back into Windows to check said files and all are fine and aren't corrupted.

Answer (score 2):

These are files that the Linux NTFS driver can't handle. They could be compressed files, duplicated files, or some other variation on a theme.

You cannot read them from a Linux based system.

If you're interested I asked a similar question over on Server Fault a while ago. See [Determine target of NTFS reparse point](https://serverfault.com/questions/742197/determine-target-of-ntfs-reparse-point).

Answer (score 1):

See how to use ntfs-3g for reading system compressed files from Windows 10 on
http://jp-andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/compression.html#systemcompression